# fitting and plotting a parabola, matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a very simple problem.
I have

```
x=[ 10 25 50];
y=[ 1.2 3 7.5];
```

I know my curve fitting function

```
f(x)=(a*x+1)/(bx+c);
```

How can I get coefficient(a,b,c) solve in matlab and also **plot** this curve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rearrange y = f(x) to make a, b, and c the unknowns:

```
y = (ax + 1) / (bx + c)
y(bx + c) = ax + 1
ax - bxy - cy = -1;
```

This describes a system of simultaneous linear equations in a, b, and c when you substitute your three paired values of x and y.

```
x      = [10, 20, 100];
y      = [1.2, 0.7, 0.4];
coeffs = [x', (-x.*y)', -y'];
knowns = [-1, -1, -1]';

v      = coeffs \ knowns;        % v is [a; b; c]
```

Now you have the coefficients a, b, and c so you can plot the function.

### Addendum: plotting

To plot a function, first choose the x-values of the data points

```
xt = 1:100;
```

Then calculate the y-values (assuming you've already got a, b, c)

```
yt = (a*x + 1) ./ (b*x + c)
```

Then just plot them!

```
plot(xt, yt);
```

Read the Matlab help on the plot function for customizing the style of the plot.

Comment: @ Brian L I have problem in plotting also. plot(x,y,'r*') will plot only points. How to fit this curve in between points.Thanx – shahbaba 5 mins ago

Comment: @shahbaba - use `plot(x,y,'r')`. The `*` option will draw only points rather than a line.

Comment: @shahbaba, @strictlyrude27 is correct about the line style, but plotting your variables `x` and `y` will only give you three data points.  It may be better to create a vector with more data points: `xt = 1:100; yt = (a*x + 1) ./ (b*x + c);` then `plot(xt, yt);`