# Plot log(n over k)

Tags: matlab, plot, logarithm, binomial-coefficients

I've never used Matlab before and I really don't know how to fix the code. I need to plot log(1000 over k) with k going from 1 to 1000.

```
y = @(x) log(nchoosek(1000,x));

fplot(y,[1 1000]);
```

Error:

```
Warning: Function behaves unexpectedly on array inputs. To improve performance, properly
vectorize your function to return an output with the same size and shape as the input
arguments. 
In matlab.graphics.function.FunctionLine>getFunction
In matlab.graphics.function.FunctionLine/updateFunction
In matlab.graphics.function.FunctionLine/set.Function_I
In matlab.graphics.function.FunctionLine/set.Function
In matlab.graphics.function.FunctionLine
In fplot>singleFplot (line 241)
In fplot>@(f)singleFplot(cax,{f},limits,extraOpts,args) (line 196)
In fplot>vectorizeFplot (line 196)
In fplot (line 166)
In P1 (line 5)
```

Comment: `nchoosek` needs a scalar input. You should use a loop to compute its result for each `k` separately. But then again, I think your exercise is meant for you to not use `nchoosek`, as the intermediate values are humongous and will likely not fit in double-precision floating point numbers (or at least give wrong results). What is the equation for log(n over k)?

Comment: this will help you https://www.tutorialspoint.com/matlab/matlab_plotting.htm

Comment: Possible duplicate of [fitting and plotting a parabola, matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7550217/fitting-and-plotting-a-parabola-matlab)

Comment: Not a duplicate at all. This question uses `fplot` (which takes an anonymous function as input), whereas the other one uses `plot` (which takes numeric vectors). Also, this question has potential numerical precision issues, due to the large numbers involved in the OP's approach

Comment: @LuisMendo Considering that his data is all discrete, it would probably make more sense for him to use plot than fplot for this application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several problems with the code:

- [`nchoosek`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/nchoosek.html) does not vectorize on the second input, that is, it does not accept an array as input. `fplot` works faster for vectorized functions. Otherwise it can be used, but it issues a warning.
- The result of `nchoosek` is close to overflowing for such large values of the first input. For example, `nchoosek(1000,500)` gives `2.702882409454366e+299`, and issues a warning.
- `nchoosek` expects integer inputs. `fplot` uses in general non-integer values within the specified limits, and so `nchoosek` issues an error.

You can solve these three issues exploiting the relationship between the factorial and the [gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function) and the fact that Matlab has [`gammaln`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/gammaln.html), which directly computes the logarithm of the gamma function:

```
n = 1000;
y = @(x) gammaln(n+1)-gammaln(x+1)-gammaln(n-x+1);
fplot(y,[1 1000]);
```

Note that you get a plot with *y* values for all *x* in the specified range, but actually the binomial coefficient is only defined for non-negative integers.

[image]

Comment: Excellent and clever exploitation of factorial and gamma function (+1). Also, I wasn't aware of the `gammaln` function.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

OK, since you've gotten spoilers for your homework exercise anyway now, I'll post an answer that I think is easier to understand.

The [multiplicative formula for the binomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Multiplicative_formula) says that

> n over k = product<sub>i=1 to k</sub>( (n+1-i)/i )

(sorry, no way to write proper formulas on SO, see the Wikipedia link if that was not clear).

To compute the logarithm of a product, we can compute the sum of the logarithms:

> log(product(x<sub>i</sub>)) = sum(log(x<sub>i</sub>))

Thus, we can compute the values of `(n+1-i)/i` for all `i`, take the logarithm, and then sum up the first `k` values to get the result for a given `k`.

This code accomplishes that using `cumsum`, the cumulative sum. Its output at array element `k` is the sum over all input array elements from 1 to `k`.

```matlab
n = 1000;
i = 1:1000;
f = (n+1-i)./i;
f = cumsum(log(f));
plot(i,f)
```

Note also `./`, the element-wise division. `/` performs a matrix division in MATLAB, and is not what you need here.

Comment: This is clever.  I hadn't considered the *sum of logs* approach but makes perfect since now that you spell it out.  Very crisp, clean approach. (+1)

Comment: Other SE site support using MathJax to render LaTex.  This seems like it would be a very useful feature on SO as well.

Comment: @John: That suggestion has been discussed and shot down on Meta multiple times. They don't want to do it, unfortunately.

Comment: @CrisLuengo  Yeah I just went down a rabbit hole investigating this.  Seems like to comes up a lot and we just live with ugly typesetting and inefficient communication because reasons...

Answer (score 2):

`syms` function type  reproduces exactly what you want

```
syms x

y = log(nchoosek(1000,x));
fplot(y,[1 1000]);
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This solution uses [`arrayfun`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/arrayfun.html) to deal with the fact that [`nchoosek(n,k)`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/nchoosek.html) requires `k` to be a scalar. This approach **requires no toolboxes**.

Also, this uses [`plot`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot.html) instead of [`fplot`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fplot.html) since [this clever answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56278219/8239061) already addresses how to do with `fplot`.

```
% MATLAB R2017a
n = 1000;
fh=@(k) log(nchoosek(n,k));  
K = 1:1000;
V = arrayfun(fh,K);    % calls fh on each element of K and return all results in vector V

plot(K,V)
```

Note that for some values of `k` greater than or equal to 500, you will receive the warning

> Warning: Result may not be exact. Coefficient is greater than 9.007199e+15 and is only accurate to 15 digits

because `nchoosek(1000,500) = 2.7029e+299`. As pointed out by [@Luis Mendo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2586922/luis-mendo), this is due to `realmax =  1.7977e+308` which is the largest real floating-point supported. See [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/realmax.html) for more info.

[image: Plot of nchoosek with n = 1000]